# How to transmit From Paypal IPN to Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, php, python, node.js, paypal

I have a system of donation that needs to be displayed in real-time to all users of my site.

However the IPN (page that is called when a payment is verified) is in PHP, and I don't think that Paypal will interpret the javascript socket.io connection infos.

So How can I transmit the payment information to a Node-js server from this page?

Maybe I can call a python script (with exec) that will send the socket via the socket.io client library for Python. But is there something easier?

Comment: IPN simlpy POSTs a value to your url; setup your node box to serve http at that url, and IPN will cause a server request. nobody else should know about that url, so you don't need any features at all, other than answering the POST request. Inside the POST, you'll find all the payment details. you should probably save them for later, but you can dispatch actions right there from the response event.

Comment: Ok, but then how can I transmit it to a node.js server so all the information can be displayed in live ?

Comment: you catch the POST with node, then use that node code to talk to your other node codes, using IPC, sockets to other, watchfiles, cluster, childProcesses, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Node.js Paypal IPN package here: https://github.com/andzdroid/paypal-ipn

Comment: How can I call it?! The paypal button just gives me the possibility to request an url... Isn't this node npm just for verifying a paypal transaction but not getting it just after the payment is made?

Comment: You configure the IPN url in your paypal account settings.